# how to get session variable when it is in "html table" form

Tags: php, session

I have problem to get the session values when the session variable is an "html table". If I write something in the session variable like `$_SESSION['value'] = 'value123';` 
then I can get the session value, but not when I try to give the session a "table and input fields", like `$_SESSION['field'] = '<table><tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="value_one" /></td></tr></table>';`  See code below.

Please will somebody give me a hint?
Thx!

```
 function function_one(){
    $content = array();

if("CONDITION"){
    $content = array(
        array(
            'title'     => '',
            'field'     => $this->blah_blah,
        ),
    );
} 
else {
    $content = array(
                array(
                    'title' => '',
                    'field' => '
                        <table>
                            <tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="value_one" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="value_two" /></td></tr>
                        </table>'
                )
            );
} 

return array(
    'id'                    => $this->blah_blah_two,
    'fields'                => $content
);      
}

 function function_two(){
if("CONDITION"){

}
$_SESSION['value'] = $content;

return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you putting the HTML into the session variable? Just put the data in the session, and generate the HTML later when you retrieve it.

Comment: unfortunately it has to be like this, otherwise i would not ask for such a scenario. but maybe you have a solution or a workaround?!

Comment: So add another session variable with the data you want. If you can't, you should use a DOM parser to get the value out of the HTML. See `DOMDocument` for more informtion on this.

Comment: What value are you trying to get out of the table, anyway? There are no variables in there, it's all just HTML.

Comment: can you maybe give me an example how you mean it? if i want only the data from the input fields from the table.
thx in advance

Comment: i want just some names or numbers

Comment: What names or numbers do you want? `value_one`? Please show examples of what you're putting in and what you want to get out.

Comment: for example
value_one should be "superman" 
and value_two should be "123456789"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) as follows:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($_SESSION['value']['content'][0]['field']);
$inputs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach ($inputs as $i) {
    echo $i->getAttribute('value') . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: thx for your example.
i'm afraid that i can't use it like this, but i will give it a try.

Comment: It's my best guess at deciphering what you're trying to do. I'm not totally sure I understood you.